# Avoid repetition in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

This question is a follow up of my previous question. I was able to match the query item and query names for the lineage thanks to the answer provided. However, I am now getting repeated query item names since the same item is used in multiple query nodes.

To explain a little bit about the XML, the dataItem "Region" is located in multiple queries and the XSL is going through and matching the root/lineage/item/name to the queries/query/selection/dataItem/expression in the XML. However since "Region" is located in multiple queries, it grabs it multiple times. I only want it once. This is a sample of the XML I am working with, :

```
<root>
  <lineage>
    <item>
      <name>[Sales (query)].[Retailers].[Retailer Province-State]</name>
      <ns>[goretailers]</ns>
      <qs>[RETAILER_SITE]</qs>
      <qi>[Retailer Province-State]</qi>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>[Sales (query)].[Products].[Product line]</name>
      <exp>#'[gosales].[PRODUCT_LINE].[PRODUCT_LINE_'+ $Language_lookup{$runLocale}+ '] '#</exp>
    </item>
  </lineage>

 <!--There is more XML code in between -->

<queries>
    <query name="RevenuMapquery">
    <!--More Code in between that is unimportant-->
    <selection>
        <dataItem name="Region">
            <expression>[AllRegion].[Region]</expression>
        </dataItem>
        <dataItem name="Revenue">
            <expression>[MeasureRevenue].[Revenue]</expression>
        </dataItem>
        <dataItem name="Planned revenue">
            <expression>[MeasureRevenue].[Planned revenue]</expression>
        </dataItem>
    </selection>
    </query>
    <query name="AllRegion">
    <source>
    <model />
    </source>
    <selection>
        <dataItem name="Region">
            <expression>[Sales (query)].[Retailers].[Retailer Province-State]</expression>
        </dataItem>
    </selection>
        <detailFilters>
        <detailFilter>
    <filterExpression>[Sales (query)].[Retailers].[Retailer country] = ('United States')    </filterExpression>
        </detailFilter>
        </detailFilters>
    </query>    
</root>
```

```
<xsl:key name="dataItems" match="dataItem" use="expression"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="lineage"/>
   </xsl:template>

<!-- The above is included at the top of the XSl stylesheet as a child of the stylesheet node -->

<xsl:for-each select="item">
   <Row>        
        <Cell Borders="#ffffff">
          <xsl:attribute name="Background">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">#CCCCFF</xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#FFFFFF</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <Paddings Left="5" Right="5" Top="2" Bottom="2"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('dataItems', name)">
              <Text Style="TableContent">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="dataItems"/>
              </Text>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </Cell>    
   </Row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The result I am getting right now is something similar to this:
Region,
Region,
Region,
Product Line,
Product Line,
Revenue, 
Revenue

The Result I want is this:
Region,
Product Line,
Revenue

Comment: Please don't refer to a pastebin from your question. It makes it harder to read, and the pastebin might not be there tomorrow. Instead, please extract the essential parts of your problem. We don't need 3 pages of XML, only the relevant parts. I understand that this requires some effort on your part, but it will substantially improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Revise your question and give us three things: (1) the source XML, (2) the desired result, and (3) the rules that we need to follow. No one can help you if you leave important bits to the imagination.

Comment: Sorry about that. Hopefully the new edits help! Let me know if you any more information or are confused about something! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use XSLT to group repetitive XML data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906406/use-xslt-to-group-repetitive-xml-data)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906406/use-xslt-to-group-repetitive-xml-data