# Use XSLT to group repetitive XML data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that needs to be transformed into a better grouping of the items.

- The items need to be counted.
- I do not know how many dogs there will
  be in the list.
- I may not know how many descriptive items about the
  dogs there will be. In the example there are three, but it could be
  any number. If this cannot be flexible, then a fixed number is ok.

Preferrably XSLT 1.0

Is this possible?

I need to go from this:

```
<table name = "dogs">
    <fields>
        <field name = "name" value = "dog1"></field>
        <field name = "age" value = "2"></field>
        <field name = "haircolor" value = "brown"></field>
        <field name = "name" value = "dog2"></field>
        <field name = "age" value = "10"></field>
        <field name = "haircolor" value = "white"></field>
        <field name = "name" value = "dog3"></field>
        <field name = "age" value = "7"></field>
        <field name = "haircolor" value = "black"></field>
        <field name = "name" value = "dog4"></field>
        <field name = "age" value = "4"></field>
        <field name = "haircolor" value = "brown"></field>
    </fields>
</table>
```

To this:

```
<dogs count = "4">
    <dog>
        <name>dog1</name>
        <age>2</age>
        <haircolor>brown</haircolor>
    </dog>
    <dog>
        <name>dog2</name>
        <age>10</age>
        <haircolor>white</haircolor>
    </dog>
    <dog>
        <name>dog3</name>
        <age>7</age>
        <haircolor>black</haircolor>
    </dog>
    <dog>
        <name>dog4</name>
        <age>4</age>
        <haircolor>brown</haircolor>
    </dog>
</dogs>
```

Comment: You need to say whether you're going to use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 because in 2.0 there's better support for grouping.

Comment: Preferrably XSLT 1.0, but if you have a solution in 2.0, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: "*I may not know how many descriptive items about the dogs there will be.*" Well, you need to know *something*, otherwise this is impossible. For example, can it be assumed that a group will always start with a name?

Comment: Hi Michael, you are right. There will be several of these tables and I will know the first field. It will not always be 'name', but I can supply it, maybe through a variable. Your solution does what asked, perfectly.

Comment: "*It will not always be 'name', but I can supply it, maybe through a variable.*" I am afraid that won't work, because you cannot use a variable in a match pattern. However, I did modify my answer to use the name of the *first* field as the 'cue' to start a new group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each group of fields starts with a *name*:
.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fields-by-lead" match="field[@name!='name']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::field[@name='name'][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:variable name="names" select="fields/field[@name='name']" />
    <dogs count="{count($names)}">
        <xsl:for-each select="$names">
            <dog>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></name>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('fields-by-lead', generate-id())">
                    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </dog>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </dogs>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

The following modification starts a new group for every field whose name matches the name of the very first field.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fields-by-lead" match="field" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::field[@name=/table/fields/field[1]/@name][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:variable name="lead-label" select="/table/fields/field[1]/@name" />
    <xsl:variable name="leads" select="fields/field[@name=$lead-label]" />
    <dogs count="{count($leads)}">
        <xsl:for-each select="$leads">
            <dog>
                <xsl:for-each select=". | key('fields-by-lead', generate-id())[@name!=$lead-label]">
                    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </dog>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </dogs>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 way of doing it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:element name="{@name}">
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="fields/field[@name = current()/fields/field[1]/@name]"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="count"><xsl:value-of select="count($fields)"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$fields"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:element name="{../../@name}">
    <name><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></name>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::field[1][not(@name = $this/@name)]" mode="trans">
      <xsl:with-param name="head-name" select="$this/@name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field" mode="trans">
  <xsl:param name="head-name"/>
  <xsl:element name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::field[1][not(@name = $head-name)]" mode="trans">
    <xsl:with-param name="head-name" select="$head-name"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to use a parameter then the code could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="head-name" select="'name'"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:element name="{@name}">
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="fields/field[@name = $head-name]"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="count"><xsl:value-of select="count($fields)"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$fields"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:element name="{../../@name}">
    <name><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></name>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::field[1][not(@name = $head-name)]" mode="trans"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field" mode="trans">
  <xsl:element name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::field[1][not(@name = $head-name)]" mode="trans">
    <xsl:with-param name="head-name" select="$head-name"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could it be that your solution will break if `@name` is not unique? I think @michael.hor257k's solution handles this correctly.

Comment: Michael has assumed the `field` starting a group has the `name` attribute with value `name`. I have assumed the `field` starting a group has the `name` attribute with the same value as the very first `field`. Of course with both solutions there can be and there are other `field` elements with different `name` attribute values, so I am not sure where you think the suggestion breaks if `@name` is not unique. The sibling recursion collects those `field`s that have a `name` attribute different from the one starting the group. So there could be `field` elements with the same name.

Comment: You're right. The dog's name is not in `@name`, it's in `@value`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Marcus, your solution works, I've managed to use it for a real test and got it working on the official XML. As with Michael's solution, the first item in the list needs to be (or will be changed to) 'name'. Could I somehow supply this as a variable, so I can use it for all the tables in the XML (there will be more)?

Comment: @Ronald, as the code simply has `<xsl:template match="table">`, it should work on any number of tables. You would normally just add a template to make sure a root element is copied over e.g. `<xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`. Instead of looking for the `name` of the first `field` you could of course also provide the name in a parameter to the stylesheet `<xsl:param name="head-name" select="'name'"/>` and then use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="fields" select="fields/field[@name = $head-name]"/>` and drop the template parameter I have used.